# Python, formula to get the monthly percentage income performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following code:

```
import datetime

total_income = {'Revenues': [100 for m in range(12)]}

current_month = datetime.date.today().month

current_revenue = total_income['Revenues'][current_month - 1]
cumulative_revenue = sum(total_income['Revenues'][:current_month])
```

All works perfectly but now I wanna get the percentage increase/decrease monthly value compared to the previous month. Ad example if `current_month = 6` I want to calculate the percentage increase/decrease compared to the may month.

Ad example:

```
current_montlhy_performance = (revenuse_jun-revenuse_may)/revenuse_may*100
```

Moreover I wanna manage all error that could arise ad example if the denominator is **equal to zero**.

Answer (score 0):

Based on

```
cumulative_revenue = sum(total_income['Revenues'][:current_month])
```

you could calculate each months revenue, like:

```
may_revenue = sum(total_income['Revenues'][may_start_date:may_end_date])
```

and use those later to calculate the performance. In order to avoid the error above, simply do a check beforehand:

```
if revenue_may > 0:
    # calculate performance
else:
    return 0
```